# Aligning my two social media divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having problems alinging two div elements next to each other on my page.

I have tried doing them in a list but that did not work. Has anybody got any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
.footer {
height:300px;
background-color:#303236;
border-top:1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.footer img:hover{
transition:2s;
}
.twitter {
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Twittergrey_zpsf9256984.png');
background-size:cover;
width:50px;
height:50px;

}
.twitter:hover {
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Twitter_zpsaa4c63a9.png');
width:50px;
height:50px;
transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.facebook {
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Facebookgrey_zps29c64b71.png');
background-size:cover;
width:50px;
height:50px;

}
.facebook:hover {
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Facebook_zpsecf6ed49.png');
width:50px;
height:50px;
transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

I uploadded it to fiddle (**HTML included in fiddle link**):
http://jsfiddle.net/ue9hbe6h/

This is what is looks like on my webpage currently:
http://bit.ly/1tFKr0Z

Any help appreciated thank you!

Comment: your demo html is invalid, I've fixed it - http://jsfiddle.net/ue9hbe6h/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your markup is wrong, close the `<a>` tags and add `float:left;` to their wrappers

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="facebook"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/alexwileydesign"></a></div>
        <div class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/alexwileydesign"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>


.footer {
    height:300px;
    background-color:#303236;
    border-top:1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.footer img:hover{
    transition:2s;
}
.twitter {
    background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Twittergrey_zpsf9256984.png');
    background-size:cover;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;

}
.twitter:hover {
    background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Twitter_zpsaa4c63a9.png');
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.facebook {
    background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Facebookgrey_zps29c64b71.png');
    background-size:cover;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;

}
.facebook:hover {
    background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/Facebook_zpsecf6ed49.png');
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

alternative is adding `display:inline-block;` to `.facebook and .twitter` if you don't want to use floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block;` to `.facebook` and `.twitter`